# Requirejs: CanvasJS.Chart is not a constructor

Tags: requirejs, amd, canvasjs

I want to use canvasjs using requirejs. The code like this:

```
require.config({
    shim: {
        'canvasjs' : {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            chart: {
                exports: 'Chart'
            }
        }
    },
    paths: {
        "jquery": "../js/jquery-1.10.2.min",
        "canvasjs": "../js/canvasjs.min"
    }
});

require(["jquery", "canvasjs"], function($, CanvasJS) {

        function AppViewModel() {
            var self = this;
        }

    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {})
    }
)
```

But the console of browser showing error like this: 
[image]

what wrong with the code ? thanks

Answer (score 3):

looks like name clashing, remove CanvasJS from callback parameter of Require call.

try following

```
require.config({
    shim: {
        'canvasjs' : {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            chart: {
                exports: 'Chart'
            }
        }
    },
    paths: {
        "jquery": "../js/jquery-1.10.2.min",
        "canvasjs": "../js/canvasjs.min"
    }
});

    require(["jquery", "canvasjs"], function($) {

            function AppViewModel() {
                var self = this;
            }

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {})
        }
    )
```